# Base Conda environment to Inbuilt Python environment

Tags: python, environment, miniconda

I mistakenly added conda (base) environment as my default environment and now every time I open my terminal, it shows (base) as my default environment instead of inbuilt python environment. I wish
to go back to my Python environment as my default environment and still want to have conda environment in my system. How can I do so?

I tried deactivating conda environment using 'conda deactivate', but when I open the terminal again , (base) shows up. I guess that is a temporary solution to deactivate the environment, but I want to permanently have my Python Inbuilt environment as default.

I have MacBook M2 Air, if it helps!
Thanks!